# Session_id(); are changing between the pages

Tags: php

`session_id();` not passing the same id number to the second page in result session file are created empty. Browser like IE and Chrome are not able to pick up session variable.

My php code.

Page2.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test3.php" method="post">
Username: <br><input type="text" name="username"></br>
<input type="submit" name = 'submit1' value= 'Login'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page3.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
echo "<br> Hi $username.</br>";
?>

<form action="test4.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name = 'submit' value= 'click me'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Page4.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "<br> Hi $username.</br>";
?>
```

Comment: You are missing the first page and you did not show where and how you are using `session_id` function

Comment: You've asked the same question four times now. Plus, `session_id();` is not even inside your posted code.

Comment: if the id changes, then your cookie settings are most likely incorrect, and you're getting a new/clean session for every page.

Comment: @Linek first page start at page2.php

Comment: @MarcB please help me regard this matter.and how to set it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved I had to change session.cookie_path in php.ini to / instead /tmp.
Thank you.